# type mismatch error: Excel VBA, loop column A for value, delete current row and rows beneath it until next value

Tags: excel, vba, loops, rowdeleting

I am having an issue with EXCEL.  I am trying to loop through some data in Column A to match those values against a list on another sheet.  If the names appear on sheet 2 it should select that row and delete it as well as delete all rows that follow that have a blank cell in column A until it reaches the next non-empty cell.

I have made some progress with your suggestions.  Here is a newer 'real life' sample of the data I have.

["Raw" data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rASaK.jpg)

and here is what it should look like after.

[Processed Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1JnS.jpg)

The VBA I am currently using is:

```
Option Explicit
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim rCrit As Range 'Range To Search For Supervisor names
Dim rFilt As Range 'Range To Remove Supervisor names
Dim lLoop As Long
Dim statsSheet As Worksheet
Dim supervisors As Worksheet


Dim i As Long 'looking for blank cells under the supervisor name
Dim values As Range
Dim counter As Integer
Set values = Range("a:a")





Set rCrit = Worksheets("supervisors").Range("A1", Worksheets
("supervisors").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set rFilt = Worksheets("statssheet").Range("A1", Worksheets 
("statssheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For lLoop = rCrit.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rCrit, rFilt(lLoop).Value) > 0 Then
        Worksheets("statssheet").Rows(lLoop).Delete shift:=xlUp
End If

       For i = 1 To values.Cells.Count - 1
 If IsEmpty(values.Cells(i)) Then
 Worksheets("statssheet").Rows(i).Delete shift:=xlUp

 End If

Next i



Next lLoop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

unfortunately when I run this code it only eliminates the top supervisor name, and it deletes ALL data for every associate and looks like this.

[This is what is currently happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s30vZ.jpg)

Comment: Step through the code with F8 and the offending line will be highlighted? Maybe Set values = Rows(rFilt) ?

Comment: rFilt doesn't have a value when you run this: Set values = Rows(rFilt)

Comment: You should NEVER, NEVER,NEVER delete rows. You must create a variant, fill it, and then print it! It will takes less than a second

Comment: Thank you for the reminder that I can step through code with F8.. I havent been using VBA long and I had forgotten all about this.. and you are correct it is at the Rows(rFilt) line that it stops.. I am trying to look for a better/working code for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your type mismatch error happens at "Set values = Rows(rFilt)". The Rows property parameter should be an integer, not a range.

Example:

```
Set values = Rows(3)
' This will return the first 3 rows of the active sheet.
```

I think there are other problems with your code, but maybe fix this one first and we'll see where we go from there.

Comment: For testing purposes I tried to change the "Set Values = Rows(rFilt)" to "Set Values = Rows(1000) because I have at least that many rows.. then when I step through the code with F8 I get a new error "Object Required".. which is confusing because it is literally defined in the line above it..